# How to grant access to Standard report type to Community users?

Tags: community, reporting

I created a Community user login history report using standard report type "Users" that is under administrative reports. I shared the report on the partner community but I am getting this error "***The source report is based on a report type that is inaccessible to the dashboard's running user***."